# Selenium C# Mstest - chromedriver.exe does not exist. Getdirectory() referring some-other directory while executing vis mstest commands

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mstest

when i'm running the selenium test from VS2017 it is able to pick the drivers successfully BUT when i run the same test using mstest command - internally it is referring some other directory!

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe/
>   testcontainer:..\Test\Sun.TestAutomation.dll /test:"myfristtest"
>   /resultsfile:..\Test\TestResultLog.trx //Mstest commands
>
> OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: The file
>   C:\Test\xsed_2018-12-07 10_55_51\Out\chromedriver.exe does not exist.
>   The driver can be downloaded at
>   http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html.

code:

```
this.DriversPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));
```

additional information:

drivers are available in debug folder why my mstest is referring the drivers in "**Out**" folder ??

Comment: Now I have a new question: Which framework are you targeting .Net Standard or .Net Framework?

Answer (score 1):

This post is a bit old but since it was brought back to the the front, this may help someone.

1. I would download the ChromeDriver Nuget package. This way you always get the latest version.
2. Right click on your project > properties. Click on Build tab.
3. set Conditional compilation symbols = _PUBLISH_CHROMEDRIVER
4. under output path set:  bin\Debug\

Once installed, clean solution and rebuild and you should see the file in the bin dir.

for your chromedriver call it should look something like this:

```
Driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.Combine(GetBasePath, @"bin\debug"), options);
```

Then add the GetBasePath code:

```
  public static string GetBasePath
    {
        get
        {
            var basePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            basePath = basePath?.Substring(0, basePath.Length - 10);
            return basePath;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This PC -> Properties -> advanced system settings -> Environment variables -> system variables -> Varible PATH add folder, where you have chromedriver.exe