# I have an error with WebDriver.dll in visual studio Chrome version must be between 70 and 73. CHROME WEB DRIVER

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have updated my chrome without thinking to much about it as I am fairly new with selenium however this has caused the following error in visual studio.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WebDriver.dll. Additional information: session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73.
```

I have tried to update the libraries but all my libraries are up to date.
Here are dose libraries and the version.

```
Selenium.Support 3.141.0
Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver 74.0.0
Selenium.WebDriver 3.141.0
NunitTestAdapter 2.1.1
```

What can I do to fix this error without downgrading chrome. Thank you very much.

UPDATE Thanks to Dazed I found In packages.config

```
<package id="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" version="73.0.3683.68" targetFramework="net461" />
```

And I replaced the version with my version.

```
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" version="74.0.3729.6" targetFramework="net461" />
```

Also my csproj has the following lines.

```
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.73.0.3683.68\build\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.73.0.3683.68\build\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.targets'))" />
  </Target>
  <Import Project="..\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.73.0.3683.68\build\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.73.0.3683.68\build\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.targets')" />
```

When I replace the 73.0.3683.68 with 74.0.3729.6 I get the following error
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Category    Suppression State

```
Error       This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.74.0.3729.6\build\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.targets.    AutoFillForm    C:\Users\Junior\Desktop\columbia project\erp_columbia\erp_columbia\AutoFillForm\AutoFillForm\AutoFillForm.csproj    106
```

Despite the fact the the files exists in my packages folder as you can see on this image.
[image: My packages]

Comment: Your driver is not compatible with Chrome 74. You must be pointing to the wrong driver or something.

Comment: What is current version of chrome browser on machine where you are running test cases?

Comment: I have the newest version of chrome  74.0.3729.157

Comment: Yes JeffC I know that but I am unable to fix it.

Comment: Delete any older chrome driver versions on the machine and get a clean chrome driver 74.0.3729.157. Some how your script is picking up the older version of chrome driver

Comment: You appear to be right there is a older version in my packages folder Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.73.0.3683.68 but when I delete it visual studio keeps downloading it back how can I prevent visual studio from doing this.

Comment: Do you have that version specified as a dependency of your project?

Comment: Meg how can verify that?

Comment: start by hitting ctrl+shift+f in VS and search for 73.0. in the entire solution. Update it to the new chromedriver value if you find any. Then pull up your csproj file for the solution. If you have more than one project in your solution, you will have more than one csproj. Search the file for chromedriver and delete the reference to the old version.

Comment: I was unable to fit my response as a comment so I updated my question. Thank you Dazed I feel that I am getting closer to an answer.

Comment: just delete the references in the csproj file and save. it will reload the project in the solution and you should be good. You probably have a similar entry for v74 in there already.

Comment: When I remove the import line I get the two following errors  
Error  Unable to copy file FILE LOCATION. The process cannot access the file OCATION because it is being used by another process.


Error  Could not copy "C:..\packages\Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver.2.45\build\..\driver\chromedriver.exe" to "C:..\bin\Debug\chromedriver.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed. AutoFillForm

Comment: go to task manager and kill all chromedriver instances

Comment: Now the program compiles however despite remove the line and saving. I still get this error An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Additional information: session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73

Comment: LMAO - you are just overcoming each issue one at a time.  go back to task manager - close out all instances of chrome and chromedriver. open one instance up of chrome and update it to current. close it and open and make sure it is the current version. Then retry automation.

Comment: that error ("Chrome version must be between 70 and 73") means your project is using the older version of Chromedriver...  something's still referring to the old chromedriver exe.

Comment: Dazed I have reboot the computer to make sure that every instance of chrome where closed and now I get this error message   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64) (SessionNotCreated)                                                                                            And on the terminal it says on port 2716 Only local connections are allowed.

Comment: You have a reference to an old driver still in your packages or csproj file for v2.45.

Comment: But I have checked in the  csproj file and in the packages files and I am pretty conviced that there are no reference to the old version. I suppose I have no chose but too start a new project with the new packages and copy paste the code from the old version.

Comment: How are you calling ChromeDriver? Did you download it, copy to a directory and have a hard coded path? Or did you use a nuget package and are calling it from a bin dir?

Comment: I just used nuget package manager just like the tutorial here told me here https://www.guru99.com/selenium-csharp-tutorial.html

Comment: yeah that step on the chrome path is not very good.  That is what you need to fix. That is pointing to the wrong driver. Using the nuget package, you would want to set it to always copy to the bin folder and then call it from there. see my post here for how to set it up  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53668341/selenium-c-sharp-mstest-chromedriver-exe-does-not-exist-getdirectory-referr/54372244#54372244

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help. It worked the only thing that I would add to your answer is that i needded to copy paste the 74.0 chromedriver and replace the old 73.0  in the bin folder.

Comment: Glad you are up and running. If you set the build tab stuff ie.  _PUBLISH_CHROMEDRIVER, when you run a build it will copy the chromedriver to the bin folder automatically. So if you clean your solution now, the bin will empty. Run a new build and the driver should be in there. The entire point of doing it this way is when you update your chromedriver again to the next version, no code changes will be required.  Now that you have that done, look at SpecFlow :).

Comment: This error may also occur when you clone a repository with a space in the name. The default name for the folder can have `%20` in the name. This is a problem. If you have this: commit and push all changes, delete the repo folder from your machine, and re-clone the repo this time to a folder with no spaces or `%20` in the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue.
To solve the issue i did following steps:

1. Go to manage nuGet packages..
2. then go to browse tab and search the package with keyword: **"Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver"**
   (For other browser, install corresponding package)
3. and then install it. (*Note:* if it is already installed then remove the package before installing it.)
4. update your chrome driver from here: http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
   and save it to your local machine and give the path of it into your code

For reference, you can visit my github page [Google Login by selenium](https://github.com/codingbyraj/GmailLoginAutomation_Selenium/)

Try to run my code by replacing your email id and password.