# Selenium C# - ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService() System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The directory name is invalid'

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting this error when try to run chrome with a different user. I cant seem to figure out why i am getting the error

the assembly directory and chromedriver.exe seems to be correct but chrome browser wont launch for some reason

Nuget package Selenium.Webdriver.ChromeDriver = 81.0.4044.13800

Chrome = Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit)

```
 private static RemoteWebDriver OpenChromeBrowser(string userName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Entering Chromesetup");
            var driverPath = CommonHelper.AssemblyDirectory;
       

            Console.WriteLine($"Assembly Directory : {driverPath}");
               var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(driverPath); //Error seems to happen here
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: checkout my answer here -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53668341/selenium-c-sharp-mstest-chromedriver-exe-does-not-exist-getdirectory-referr/54372244#54372244

Comment: just to add:
Selenium.Webdriver.ChromeDriver = 81.0.4044.13800
Chrome  = Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: you should update the driver to latest but the solution in that link will resolve your issue. That will work regardless if your solution is installed on C: and Jenkins is on E: as an example.

Comment: I tried with your method and got the exact same error. confused now

Comment: What does your call look like now to open the browser?

Comment: `var driverPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);`
`driverPath = driverPath?.Substring(0, driverPath.Length - 10);`

`var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(driverPath, @"bin\Debug\chromedriver.exe");`

//some more code 

`return new ChromeDriver(service, options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what my full call looks like for the most part for chrome. You should not be calling chromedriver.exe in your call. Just use the directory for the location of the file.

```
                    ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(Path.Combine(GetBasePath, @"bin\Debug\"));
                    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                    options.AddArguments("--incognito");
                    driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
                    driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();


            public static string GetBasePath
    {
        get
        {
            var basePath =
                System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName((System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
            basePath = basePath.Substring(0, basePath.Length - 10);
            return basePath;
        }
    }
```